# SQL - Return field from sub sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

How do I bring back a second name field from the ug1 table?

```
select ug.name, ug.email, ug
from user_group as ug
where ug.id in (SELECT gm.id_user FROM group_member as gm
                where id_group in (SELECT ug1.id from user_group as ug1
                                   where ug1.btype='g'
                                     and ug1.group_type_handle = 'leaversys'))
```

Comment: You can't, you will have to JOIN instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` instead of `in` if you want the fields:

```
select ug.name, ug.email, . . .
from user_group ug join
     group_member gm
     on ug.id = gm.id_user join
     user_group ug2
     on gm.id_group = ug2.id 
where ug2.btype = 'g' and ug2.group_type_handle = 'leaversys';
```

This is not exactly the same, because it can result in multiple rows.  However, I suspect that will not be an issue in your case.

Now you can include whatever columns you want from the three tables.